# Why does HTML source code change while extracting text from soup object?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape news articles from the results of a search term using Selenium and BeautifulSoup on Python. I have arrived at the final page which contains the text using:

```py
article_page = requests.get(articles.link_of_article[0])
article_soup = BeautifulSoup(article_page.text, "html.parser")
for content in article_soup.find_all('div',{"class":"name_of_class_with_contained_text"}):
     content.get_text()
```

I notice that `"name_of_class_with_contained_text"` is present when I visually inspect the source code in the browser but the class is not present in the soup object. Also, all the `"p"` tags are replaced with the following code `"\\u003c/p\\u003e\\u003cp\\u003e \\u003c/p\\u003e\\u003cp\\u003e"`.

I am unable to find the class name or tags to get the text contained.
Any help or reasoning as to why this happens would be appreciated.

P.S: Relatively new to scraping and HTML

UPDATE:Adding the link of the final page here.

https://www.fundfire.com/c/2258443/277443?referrer_module=searchSubFromFF&highlight=eileen%20neill%20verus

Comment: please provide the link

Comment: in question you should add url to this page and then we can check it.

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add this item then you can't get it with `Beautifulsoup` because it can't run JavaScript. You would have to use `Selenium` to control browser which can run JavaScript and then get HTML from Selenium (`driver.page_source`), not using `requests` which also can't run JavaScript.

Comment: We need to be able to reproduce the issue so as per comments above please include the url.

Comment: @QHarr - I've added the link to the page that is to be scraped

Comment: @furas - The final link to the page has been added in the question

Comment: I don't see any `<p> ` in HTML and I don't know what class you search - you didn't use real name in code. But I see button "LOGIN" on page and maybe in browser you saw page after login - but `BeautifulSoup` is not logged in. HTML which you get in script you should save in file and open in browser to see what you get.